# Spring request mapping: Matching with url pattern

Tags: spring, servlets, spring-mvc

I have a web application with Spring MVC.

web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/companies/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

spring controller method:

```
class RealmInfoController{

    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = {"/companies/{companyId}/realms/{realmName}"})
    public RealmInfo realmInfo(@PathVariable long companyId, @PathVariable String realmName)
```

Handler match:

```
http://localhost:6122/context/companies/15877/realms/firstRealm
```

When the server gets this url, the spring servlet gets called. but it cannot match the controller method.

But if I change the request mapping to "/{companyId}/realms/{realmName}" then it matches the controller method. But it is not nice to define the url mapping without '/companies'. Can Spring be instructed in some way to look for match including the url pattern specified in the servlet?

Thanks.

Comment: Because in the `<url-pattern>` there is `/companies/*` path, you are telling the container to invoke _DispatherServlet_ whenever the URL matches the defined pattern. So in the controller you MUST NOT include `/companies/` part in the _@RequestMapping_ - **it is already included**. In other words, **not including `/companies/` part in the _@RequestMapping_ is the right way** of doing it in your case.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use "companies" in request mapping you should map your dispatcher servlet to the root:

```
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
```

Comment: i could not use <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> or <url-pattern>/</url-pattern> because is hides other servlets and error-page definitions.

Comment: @Rag Then just do as you were doing it before. As I wrote you in the comment above - not including `/companies/` in the `@RequestMapping` is the right way in your case.